# Save hidden Excel sheets to a file generated with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save hidden Excel sheets to a file generated via button with Excel VBA.

How can I modify this code so it copies only the hidden sheets?

```
Sub Generate_matriz()   

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sheet_exp = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    fecha = Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy")
    Export = fecha & "_matriz_sovio"

    FileSelected = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Export, _                                            
      FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlxs), *.xlxs", Title:="Save Excel as")

    If FileSelected = False Then Exit Sub

    Sheets(sheet_exp).Visible = True

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileSelected _
      , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    MsgBox ("It was successfully recorded : " & FileSelected), 
    vbInformation, "SOVIO"

    Sheets(sheet_exp).Visible = false
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, it will loop through your worksheets and if visible, it will hide them and if hidden, then it will show them, then save the workbook and revert back to show the appropriate worksheets:

```
Sub Generate_matriz()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    fecha = Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy")
    Export = fecha & "_matriz_sovio"

    FileSelected = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Export, _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlxs), *.xlxs", Title:="Save Excel as")

    If FileSelected = False Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Or ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next ws

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileSelected _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    MsgBox ("It was successfully recorded : " & FileSelected), vbInformation, "SOVIO"

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Or ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you to answering, but i need only hidden Excel sheets to generated one file.

Comment: @Kais the answer I posted should only generate a single file, do you mean that you would like to remove the visible worksheets from the new workbook completely instead of hiding them?